# How to rewrite url for remove umbraco/surface from url in umbraco?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco7

I have created a link for Logout

`<a href="@Url.Action("Logout","UserSurface")" title="Log out">Log out</a>`

Now url become

```
"domainname.com/umbraco/Surface/ControllerName/Logout"
```

Now I want to remove /umbraco/Surface from url.
So Url will become

```
"domainname.com/ControllerName/ActionName"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem, but with most things Umbraco related the payoff isn't worth the effort.

Here's a fairly dirty solution I use.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString NonUmbracoAction(this UrlHelper helper, string action, string controller)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString(helper.Action(action, controller).Replace("umbraco/Surface/", ""));
    }
```